# Xamarin, Android - Blur whole activity when a drawer is shown or an alert is visible

Tags: c#, android

This has been asked a lot, yes I know - it hasn't been asked regarding Xamarin - that is why I am hoping to clarify this.

Anyway -

we all know what an alert is and what it looks like. In my activity, I use those, as well as sidedrawers a lot.
An example of a nice alert:

```
 btnAvatarOfFriend.Click += delegate
            {
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetMessage("Hey there! I added you as my friend to follow your profile! Would you like to add me back? :-)");

                alert.SetPositiveButton("Befriend Me!", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {

                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Not yet possible", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                });

                alert.SetNegativeButton("Visit My Profile!", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Not yet possible", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                });

                alert.SetNeutralButton("Dismiss Me!", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {
                    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -2000, 0, 0);
                    animation.FillAfter = true;
                    animation.SetInterpolator(this, Android.Resource.Animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator);
                    animation.Duration = intDurationOfAnimation;
                    btnAvatarOfFriend.StartAnimation(animation);
                    txtNameOfFriend.StartAnimation(animation);
                    txtSubLineFriends.StartAnimation(animation);

                    animation.AnimationEnd += delegate
                    {
                        linlayForLoop.RemoveAllViews();
                    };
                });

                Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
                dialog.Show();
            };
```

So, when I click on an avatar in my activity, this is the result:

[image]

Now, what the alert already does is to blacken the background out a little bit. 
However, this is not enough for us today!

The result that I wish would happen is the following:
(photoshop worked its magic here)

[image]

So, basically the background doesnt ONLY fade it also blurres away.
What I need to know now:

How can I get the whole activity to blurry out? Maybe via the use of a timer that increases the radius in whithin .5 of a second. So that it gets a little animation? The answer to that is a mystery I really hope any of you guys could solve.

Please bear in mind that this is C# NOT java!

One last thing - I have happend to find this:

```
    this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.BlurBehing);
```

But it did nothing. 
Help would be awesome :)
THANKS!